# Panda's Interact and IntSlider (ipywidgets) not displaying slider in jupyter

Tags: jupyter, ipywidgets

Please help me.

I am following this Lynda tutorial - [Python Statistics Essential Training](https://www.lynda.com/Python-tutorials/power-visualization/711826/765276-4.html?autoplay=true) - Chapter 3, The power of visualization.

and the slider isn't showing up in Jupyter, it's not interactive as it's supposed to be. I run the "end" file, and it also has that issue. I have ipywidgets installed and json.   [image of the end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIU1v.png)

```
interact(plotyear,year=widgets.IntSlider(min=1950,max=2015,step=1,value=1965))
```

Thank you for reading my question. Looking forward to finding a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Bit difficult to diagnose this one given that we can't see the code.

Firstly, what version of ipywidgets do you have? run `help(widgets)` once you have imported ipywidgets.

Also, can you try running this and see what happens? Can you see a slider and a number that outputs when you change it?

```python
import ipywidgets as widgets

def return_x(x):
    return x

widgets.interact(return_x, x=widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=10, value=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

first: jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
second: jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager

After this installation, the test code from ac24 works.